# keyboard not appearing when uitextfield is pressed

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

1. I have presented a navigation controller (Nav1) as modal view controller from rootViewController
2. Then from Nav1 i created another navigation controller (Nav2) and presented it as modal view controller.
3. In nav2 when i click a table cell it pushes a view controller containing UITextField

Now the problem is when I click on UITextField it does not show iphone keyboard

Actually I am trying to make something like alarm label as in iphone clock app.

Answer (score 1):

Just be sure for you have set the delegate the textfield...

```
[textField setDelegate:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

why did you choose two nav controllers?

you can use tabbarcontroller by the way there is much more simpler way to achieve this.Search on google

Answer (score 0):

check if
"reloadData"
is not executing before the UITextField becomes active

Comment: It is actually a comment